# Wie bildet man "etwas sein wollen"

Tags: verb, sentence-structure, infinitive, subordinate-clause

Jemand hat zu mir gesagt

> […], weil ich will sein eine Übersetzerin.

In dem Versuch zu erklären, dass das „weil ich eine Übersetzerin sein will“ heißen würde, ist mir aufgefallen, dass ich eigentlich keine Ahnung von der deutschen Grammatik habe und nicht erklären kann warum.

In dem Satz

> Ich will eine Übersetzerin sein

kommt das *will* vor dem *sein*, in folgendem ist es jedoch dahinter.

> Ich lerne Deutsch, weil ich eine Übersetzerin sein will

Unter welchen Bedingungen steht das *will* vor dem *sein* und wann dahinter?

Comment: Alles klar, so kann ich die Frage beantworten ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Die beiden Verben sind nicht gleichberechtigt im Satz. Egal, wer ihn ausspricht, das *sein* wird sich nicht verändern, es wird immer ein *sein* bleiben. Diese Form heißt Infinitiv. Das *will* dagegen verändert sich je nachdem wer den Satz ausspricht (wer also das Subjekt ist). Es hieße zum Beispiel:

> Du will**st** eine Übersetzerin sein.

Das Verb, das sich nach dem Subjekt des Satzes beugt, nennt man *finites Verb;* von einem solchen finiten Verb hängen Infinitive ab. Das finite Verb kann – wie in diesem Fall – ein Hilfsverb *(wollen)* sein, oder es ist ein anderes Vollverb, dann enthält der Infinitiv in der Regel das Wörtchen *zu.*

Die Stellung der Verben zueinander hängt von der Satzform ab. In einem Hauptsatz steht das finite Verb immer an zweiter Stelle, nicht-finite Bestandteile des Verbs – also vor allem von ihm abhängige Infinitive – an letzter. Zusammengefasst nennt man das die *Verbklammer,* in der sich der Großteil des Satzes versteckt. Das, was vor der Verbklammer steht, muss nicht das Subjekt sein. Vergleiche:

> Eine Übersetzerin will ich sein.

In einem Nebensatz herrscht im Deutschen Verbendstellung, das heißt, dass das finite Verb stets an *letzter* Stelle steht. Der andere Teil der Verbklammer bleibt, wo er ist; in einfachen Sätzen sieht es also so aus als hätten beide die Plätze getauscht. Nebensätze sind solche, die einem Hauptsatz untergeordnet sind, und die von einem entsprechenden Einleitewort (unterordnende Konjunktion), wie zum Beispiel *dass, wenn, obwohl, der/die/das, …* eingeletet werden.

Also: Dein mittlerer Beispielsatz ist ein Hauptsatz; in ihm steht das finite Verb *wollen* an zweiter Stelle. Dein letzter Beispielsatz ist ein Nebensatz, in dem das finite Verb an letzter Stelle steht. Falls du genau hingeschaut hast, dürftest du den gleichen Unterschied eben wiedererkannt haben.

In vielen anderen Sprachen folgt ein Infinitiv (fett) in der Regel direkt dem Vollverb (kursiv), zum Beipiel:

> I *want* **to be** a translator. (English)
>
> Je *veux* **devenir** traductrice. (Französisch)
>
> (Minä) *haluan* **olla** kääntäjä. (Finnisch)

---

Nebeninformation: Eine Verbklammer muss nicht aus Infinitiv und finitem Verb bestehen. Auch ein trennbares Verb kann eine solche bilden:

> Ich **gebe** das Übersetzen **auf.**
>
> …, weil ich das Übersetzen **aufgebe.**

Oder eine Verbform im Perfekt:

> Ich **bin** eine Übersetzerin **geworden.**
>
> …, weil ich eine Übersetzerin **geworden bin.**

Vorsichtig muss man auch bei erweiterten Infinitiven sein; die schließen sich gerne zur Klarheit auch *hinter* der Verbklammer an (dann aber oft mit Komma):

> Ich will lernen, um eine Übersetzerin zu sein.
>
> …, weil ich lernen wollte, eine Übersetzerin zu sein.

Comment: Wow! Vielen herzlichen Dank für die mehr als ausführliche Antwort, damit hätte ich nicht gerechnet, das ist genau die Art von Antwort die ich mir erhofft habe :)

Comment: Danke auch für die Mühe meine Frage zu editieren! (schade, dass du das *dass* übersehen hast)

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 Ach, niemand ist perfekt, was edits angeht ;) Und ich bin eigentlich auch nur hinter dem Orden her ;D

Comment: So war das nicht gemeint :) Ich schäme mich nur, dass das dass immer noch da steht :P

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 Du kannst auch selber editieren ;D

Comment: Klar doch :D aber doch nicht um ein Zeichen zu ändern, das würde die Frage nur unnötig nach oben befördern und zumindest auf Stackoverflow sind so kleine änderungen nicht so gerne gesehen :)

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 Achso? Gut, dass ich mich nicht auf SO aufhalte, weil ich eig. immer Rechtschreibfehler uä rauskorrigiere (vor allem aus meinen eigenen Posts) wenn ich sie sehe. Aber wie du auf unserer Hauptseite siehst ist das Fragenvolumen hier nicht vergleichbar mit SO; so ein Schönheitsedit darf hier ruhig sein ^__^